# C++ Perfect Number With Nested Loops Issue

Tags: c++, loops, nested, boolean, perfect-numbers

What I am trying to do is search for a perfect number.
A perfect number is a number that is the sum of all its divisors, such as 6 = 1+2+3.

Basically what I do here is ask for 2 numbers and find a perfect number between those two numbers. I have a function that tests for divisibility and 2 nested loops.

My issue is that I don't get any result. I've revised it & can't seem to find anything wrong. The compiler doesn't shoot out any errors.

What can be wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isAFactor(int, int);

int main()
{

int startval;
int endval;
int outer_loop;
int inner_loop;
int perfect_number = 0;

cout << "Enter Starting Number: ";
cin >> startval;
cout << "Enter Ending Number: ";
cin >> endval;

for(outer_loop = startval; outer_loop <= endval; outer_loop++)
{
    for(inner_loop = 1; inner_loop <= outer_loop; inner_loop++)
    {
        if (isAFactor(outer_loop, inner_loop) == true)
        {
            inner_loop += perfect_number;
        }
    }

if (perfect_number == outer_loop)
{
    cout << perfect_number << " is a perfect number." << endl;
}

else
{
    cout << "There is no perfect number." << endl;
}

}

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}

bool isAFactor(int outer, int inner)
{
if (outer % inner == 0)
{
    return true;
}

else
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a *debugger*?

Comment: You are reading a string into an int value.  That doesn't work.  You have to read into a character array, and convert the first character(s) into an integer.

Comment: @SethBattin: try the questioner's code, you'll see that part of it is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inner_loop += perfect_number;` should be `perfect_number += inner_loop;`.

There are other issues -- you need to reset `perfect_number` to zero in each outer loop, and you should presumably print the message `"There is no perfect number."` if none of the numbers in range is perfect, rather than printing it once for every number in range that is not perfect.

I'd advise that you rename `perfect_number` to `sum_of_factors`, `outer_loop` to `candidate_perfect_number` and `inner_loop` to `candidate_factor`, or similar.

Comment: Also, `perfect_number` will need to get reset each time through the outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

after the if statement:

```
cout << perfect_number;
cout << outer_loop;

if (perfect_number == outer_loop)
{
    cout << perfect_number << " is a perfect number." << endl;
}
```

and see what values they have

**Updated:**

What is the value of your endval? is 0?, and thats why the loop ends so early

Answer (score 0):

Oh, so many issues.

1. The variable `perfect_number` never changes.  Did your compiler flag
   this?
2. The outer loop will be one more than the ending value when it exits;
   did you know this?
3. You don't need to compare `bool` values to `true` or `false`.
4. You could simplify the `isAFactor` function to `return (outer %
   inner) == 0;`.
5. You could replace the call to `isAFactor` with the expression
   `((outer % inner) == 0)`.

Comment: (1) is an error, (2) is fine (at least, provided endval != INT_MAX, that's a nasty corner case), (3) and (4) are redundant code that should be cleaned up but don't stop the program working, (5) is a matter of whether, philosophically speaking, you feel that subroutines are a good thing :-) Actually I think this code could benefit from *more* different functions rather than fewer.

Comment: Btw, what compiler option do I need to get a warning for `perfect_number` not being modified? That's a pretty fussy compiler, to nag you to mark it `const`. Why warn for `perfect_number` in `main` and not for (say) `outer` in `isAFactor` being non-const but never modified?